# How to delete recently created Google Contact?

Tags: c#, google-contacts-api

I am temporary creating one contact and immediatly after that i want to delete that contact.
I am creating contact as follows:

```
ContactEntry[] ContactEntry = new ContactEntry[2];
ContactEntry[0] = new ContactEntry();
ContactEntry[0].Title.Text = "Temp";

Uri feedUri = new Uri(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));
ContactEntry createdEntry = (ContactEntry)obj_ContactService.Insert(feedUri, ContactEntry[0]);
```

In order to delete above contact if i use:

```
ContactEntry[0].Delete();
```

It is throwing Exception : "No Service object set".

Note: I am using Google Apps API Ver 2 for .NET

Comment: I would love the know what it is you are trying to do. Why can't you just keep that temp contact for use as a temp. It would also make sense to name it so, rather then have it as the first element of an array.

Comment: I want to learn how to delete contact.Why it is not working in above case?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than deleting the original data holder object you should delete the instance you got from the google server. Like this:

```
createdEntry.Delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help you out... 
http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#Deleting

**Edit:** As the API says, you need a ContactRequest instance to call the Delete method. I dont see that in the snippet you posted